# Magento 2: Conditionally process layout XML file

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have an XML layout file, specifically `customer_account_login.xml`, which is processed automatically by Magento and replaces the out-of-the-box copy.

In some cases I would like to do this, while in others I want the out-of-the-box file (based on backend configuration).

I have not found a way to turn off processing for my XML file under certain conditions, but assume there is some class that can be overridden to do this. A generic way would be preferable, but I could live with a method that toggles just this specific XML file.

To clarify: the question is about avoiding processing the XML file entirely, not how to conditionally show/hide certain blocks and other layout elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ifconfig** parameter on your node to enable/disable it on the basis of value of a specified field in system configuration [`system.xml`].

You can specify the field from system.xml by mentioning `ifconfig="section/group/field"` from your `system.xml`. Preferably keep the field to be a select of yes/no type.

Feel free to ask any queries in case of confusion.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I am after. `ifconfig` only works with blocks, which is problematic (try containers), and it's also more difficult to remove elements (can be done with `action` but not in all cases, and requires a convoluted structure). The biggest problem however, is the fact that the file needs to be processed at all, I'd like for it to be completely ignored in some cases.

Comment: As far as if know ifconfig is the only condition processing in layout xmls of magento. Please do post the answer here if you find anything else.